# Unable to use "regex" within scrapy

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I use `regex` within `scrapy`? I've searched a lot but could not find any good instruction to go with. However, I've tried like following but it throws an exception which I'm gonna paste below.

```
import requests, re
from scrapy import Selector

LINK = 'http://www.viperinnovations.com/products-and-services/cableguardian'

def get_item(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    sel = Selector(res)
    email = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+',sel)[0]
    print(email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_item(LINK)
```

The exception it throws upon execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo.py", line 13, in <module>
    get_item(LINK)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo.py", line 9, in get_item
    email = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+',sel)[0]
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The email within my scraper above is just a placeholder. All I wanna know is how can I use `regex` within `scrapy`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: A `Selector` isn't a string, it's a thing you can use to select substrings out of the raw data. So I'm not sure what you want `re.findall(…, sel)` to do. If you want to select the entire input, you can do that via `sel.extract()`, but that's kind of pointless; it's easier to just pass the whole string than to select the whole string and pass the result. If you want it to do something different, you need to explain what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Selector`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) isn't a string, it's an object that knows how to run queries on an HTML string or response object to find sub-elements.

Once you've found the element or elements you want (it will find a list of elements if there are any non-singular queries), the `extract` method will let you get the text of the found element or elements.

For example:

```
>>> Selector(text=body)
<Selector (text)>
>>> Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()')
<Selector (text) xpath=//title/text()>
>>> Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').extract()
['First span', 'Second span', 'Third span']
```

It's only the last one you can do anything useful to with a regex:

```
>>> [match
...  for text in Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').extract()
...  for match in re.findall(r'[a-z]*\s', text)]
['irst ', 'econd ', 'hird ']
```

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, for such an excellent solution. Much obliged.